# Building FreeImage.net on Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, freeimage

It display 39 errors. All errors are like this:

Error   1   Warning as Error: XML comment on 'FreeImageAPI.Plugins.PluginRepository.Plugin(string)' has a typeparamref tag for 'expression', but there is no type parameter by that name    C:\Users\Public\Documents\@Programming\FreeImage\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs\Library\Classes\PluginRepository.cs   63  27  Library

on source file:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Returns an instance of <see cref="FreeImageAPI.Plugins.FreeImagePlugin"/>.
        /// <typeparamref name="expression"/> is searched in:
        /// <c>Format</c>, <c>RegExpr</c>,
        /// <c>ValidExtension</c> and <c>ValidFilename</c>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="expression">The expression to search for.</param>
        /// <returns>An instance of <see cref="FreeImageAPI.Plugins.FreeImagePlugin"/>.</returns>
        public static FreeImagePlugin Plugin(string expression)
        {
            FreeImagePlugin result = null;
            expression = expression.ToLower();

            foreach (FreeImagePlugin plugin in plugins)
            {
                if (plugin.Format.ToLower().Contains(expression) ||
                    plugin.RegExpr.ToLower().Contains(expression) ||
                    plugin.ValidExtension(expression, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                    plugin.ValidFilename(expression, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    result = plugin;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

How do i fix it ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried to remove the comment?

Comment: @bryanmac : no, is it ok to remove them ?

Comment: I tried to remove the comment, the error turns into: Error 1 Warning as Error: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member 'FreeImageAPI.Plugins.PluginRepository.Plugin(string)' C:\Users\Public\Documents\@Programming\FreeImage\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs\Library\Classes\PluginRepository.cs 62 33 Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `<typeparamref name="expression"/>` to `<paramref name="expression"/>`.
`<typeparamref>` is intended to describe a type parameter (as in generics) and not the name of a parameter that is received by the method.

[Check typeparamref here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173192%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [paramref here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb7x2fhw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing and I solved it by:

1. Right click on your project and select 'Properties'.
2. Select the 'Build' tab on the left side.
3. Go to the 'Treat warnings as errors' section and select 'None'.